# Why does <svg> leave containing <div>?

Tags: css, html, svg

Here's some SVG I'm trying to get working, the characters are positioned funny (but that is good), but what isn't good is that the whole SVG is supposed to be inside a `<div>` inside the `<h1>`, but it seems to jump down below. I added what I thought should be an unnecessary `top: 0;` style, and it didn't help.

The second thing I don't understand is why the "svg sample" text in the  gets shoved to the bottom... likely something to do with baseline alignment, I suppose, but I don't understand it, and I don't know how to fix it.

```css
body,
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding-top: 53px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 47px;
  margin-right: 53px;
  padding-left: 53px;
  border: 3px solid;
  font-size: 25pt;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#screen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.world {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.world svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.world div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen">
  <h1>
    <div class="world" style="height: 47px; width: 94px;">
      <div>
        <svg class="h1world" viewBox="0 -200 560 280">
          <text x="0 30 60 150 152" y="0 0 -30 -30 -90">Hello</text>
          <line id="staff" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span> &nbsp; svg sample</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div`s are not valid within `h1`s, according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html).

In my snippet below, I:

1. Changed `h1` to a class and assigned it to a `div`.
2. Added `vertical-align: top` to the `world` class.
3. Added `float: left` to the `svg` class.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 53px;
}

.h1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 47px;
  margin-right: 53px;
  padding-left: 53px;
  border: 3px solid;
  font-size: 25pt;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#screen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.world {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.world svg {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen">
  <div class="h1">
    <div class="world" style="height: 47px; width: 94px;">
      <svg class="h1world" viewBox="0 -200 560 280">
        <text x="0 30 60 150 152" y="0 0 -30 -30 -90">Hello</text>
        <line id="staff" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <span> &nbsp; svg sample</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to note, the browsers don't seem to mind having <div> inside <h1>, and I never knew it was illegal... and it made no difference to this problem.  vertical-align: middle; looks a little better to me than top; and the float cured the location of the <svg>... but I don't really understand _why_ it needs to be floated, or even why that helps... the top: 0; is useless and can be removed.

Comment: You're absolutely right about `div`s working within `h1`s, even though it goes against the spec.  And you're correct that this was not the reason for your problem.  I just hacked away until I arrived at the solution, and while doing so, I wondered if the `div` within the `h1` may be contributing the problem.

Comment: I don't quite understand why the float is required either.  I tried it in case the browser was adding whitespace before the svg, because the svg was on a separate line.  I'll try to come up with a better explanation!

Comment: Thanks, Rick. I'm starting down the path of using SVG graphics for some pages, and was quite surprised to see this behavior show up. Without understanding why, it is hard to predict when or where it might show up again! In any case, it was a successful try, and cured a rather bizarre behavior, but I'm left wondering if I need to wrap every <svg> into a <div> just so I can float it... well, I'll press forward with some more experiments to see if I can get the rest of my page designed (please realize this was an extraction to demonstrate a problem, and from an experiment, not my real page).

Comment: SVG is new to me as well, so I have some studying on my own to do.  It is certainly surprising behavior.

Comment: I'm trying to grok http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/ especially part 3, lots of information there, mostly about the _internal_ behavior of <svg>, not the boundary between <div> and <svg>.